# Jmeter Groovy how can I replace this string with {

Tags: groovy, jmeter

In Jmeter with JSR223 Groovy .. I have spent a lot of time trying to replace this string in a JSON block

```
"ABC": {"seconds": 20},
```

with

```
"ABC": {"seconds": ${myVal}}, (this way my value in seconds is variable)
```

I have tried

```
str1 = str1.replaceAll('"ABC": {"seconds": 20}', '"ABC": {"seconds": '+${myVal}+'"}"');
```

but it wont work. please help,

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
def s = '''
{"ABC": {"seconds": 20}, 
 "DEF": {"seconds": 30}, 
 "IJK": {"seconds": 40}} 
'''

def myVal = 88
def oldRegex = /"ABC": \{"seconds": 20\}/
def newStr = '"ABC": {"seconds": ' + myVal + '}'
def s2 = s.replaceAll(oldRegex, newStr);

println s2
```

Note that the first parameter of `replaceAll` is a regular expression, which means that `{` and `}` must be escaped. When escaping chars in Groovy, we generally prefer `/\{/` (a slashy-string) instead of `"\\{"`.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing values in JSON using regular expressions is not the best idea as it will be very fragile and any extra space or line break will ruin your test.

I would recommend going for [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) and [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) classes combination instead. Moreover, don't refer JMeter Variables as `${myVal}`, a way better option would be `vars.get('myVal')`.

Full example code just in case:

```
vars.put('myVal', '1234')

def foo = '{\n' +
        '  "ABC": {\n' +
        '    "seconds": 20\n' +
        '  }\n' +
        '}'

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(foo)
json.ABC.seconds = vars.get('myVal') as int
log.info(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(json).toPrettyString())
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Replace Value in JSON]

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and Producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)