# How to replace file content which has special character, with dynamic value in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Can I replace a file content with dynamic content even if the file has special characters.

This is what I get when I try to do that.
[image]

and this is how my file looks like

```
[{"someName": "M`o\c\k","someNumber": "${randomNumber}"}]
```

and I have a variable configured for `${randomNumber}`.

Comment: Which file you are referring to? Text, CSV etc...Are you trying to put the content in a file and fetching them at runtime which contains special character?

Comment: The file showed in the snapshot is stores.json, I am trying to load it at run time. inject some variables to it, encode it, and then pass it to a WebSocket request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my scenario by adding a json library to my JMeter, [JSON.Simple](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1). I added the jar to my [jmeter classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399808/add-all-jars-from-a-folder-to-jmeter-classpath). Then I was able to a `BeanShell PreProcessor`.

[image]

The Json simple object will not escape the special characters and its much easier to manipulate. So that was great for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the below can met your requirement.

Random Variable Config:-
[image]
Dummy sampler for the json
[image]
JSR223 Post processor to put the dummy response in a variable
[image]
Used the variable in HTTP. This is just for demo. Probably, in your case it will be websocket.
[image]
Output
[image]

Also, groovy provide json support. Below you can check a similar solution based on groovy. Where it is mentioned to escape special character for json.

[Jmeter Groovy how can I replace this string with {](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574355/jmeter-groovy-how-can-i-replace-this-string-with)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This can help in solving my problem, but it's a lot of elements to work around it, and in my case I am working with multiple files. I will share my solution for it and hopefully this will help others who have a similar scenario.